# How to parse the xml start tag to end tag using shellscript?

Tags: shell-script, xml

I have XML file like below, called `sample.xml`:

```xml
<m:properties>
<d:>ABCD</d:>
<d:>1234</d:>
<d:>0048</d:>
<d:>0.0</d:>
</m:properties>
<m:properties>
<d:>EFGH</d:>
<d:>5678</d:>
<d:>1111</d:>
<d:>9.0</d:>
</m:properties>
```

The required output is:

```
ABCD,1234,0048,0.0
EFGH,5678,1111,9.0
```

Can anyone help me to create the script?

Comment: Is the XML document not enclosed in a single root tag?

Comment: Yes, we can help. Create it and you'll find someone to assist with any problems that arise. Did you decide which XML parser to use?

Comment: If `sample.xml` doesn't contain a root element of some sort then it is not XML. Similarly, it should have (at least one) namespace declaration for the `d:` and `m:` namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML is enclosed in a single root tag called `root`, using a permissive XML parser like `xq` (part of `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to create CSV:

```bsh
xq -r '.root."m:properties"[]."d:" | @csv' sample.xml
```

If there is no enclosing tag like this, then we can add one on the fly:

```bsh
{
  echo '<root>'
  cat sample.xml
  echo '</root>'
} | xq -r '.root."m:properties"[]."d:" | @csv'
```

Result:

```
"ABCD","1234","0048","0.0"
"EFGH","5678","1111","9.0"
```